# How do I get a section that contains few lines of text and next half text and half part images

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How do I achieve this following type of result using HTML, CSS and Bootstrap?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without bootstrap. To get the image inline with your text, you can use `float: right` on the image.  Here is a simple inline CSS example:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sagittis pulvinar nulla, scelerisque viverra lorem pellentesque non. Phasellus ligula leo, facilisis eget<p>

<p>Proin sit amet elit eget dolor sagittis blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed sollicitudin ullamcorper mi sit amet pretium. Nam quis pulvinar purus. <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="float:right" />Integer eget lobortis justo, a porta odio. In non lacinia leo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>

<p>Nullam elementum, justo et ornare semper, sapien arcu ornare nunc, a laoreet tortor neque sit amet dui. Aenean eleifend nibh nec tempus interdum. Nulla augue purus, scelerisque in massa sed, fringilla tempor nisl. Nam tincidunt porta nibh, in pharetra quam pellentesque ac. Nunc metus turpis, rhoncus eu mauris eu, hendrerit suscipit tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent odio nisi, venenatis ac scelerisque vel, pharetra et eros. Vivamus at elementum mauris, nec consequat odio. Quisque volutpat pharetra mollis. Curabitur tempor orci in auctor ultrices. Aliquam condimentum elementum euismod.</p>
```

If you really want to use bootstrap though, you can add the pull-right class to the image, like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sagittis pulvinar nulla, scelerisque viverra lorem pellentesque non. Phasellus ligula leo, facilisis eget<p>

<p>Proin sit amet elit eget dolor sagittis blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed sollicitudin ullamcorper mi sit amet pretium. Nam quis pulvinar purus. <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="pull-right" />Integer eget lobortis justo, a porta odio. In non lacinia leo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>

<p>Nullam elementum, justo et ornare semper, sapien arcu ornare nunc, a laoreet tortor neque sit amet dui. Aenean eleifend nibh nec tempus interdum. Nulla augue purus, scelerisque in massa sed, fringilla tempor nisl. Nam tincidunt porta nibh, in pharetra quam pellentesque ac. Nunc metus turpis, rhoncus eu mauris eu, hendrerit suscipit tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent odio nisi, venenatis ac scelerisque vel, pharetra et eros. Vivamus at elementum mauris, nec consequat odio. Quisque volutpat pharetra mollis. Curabitur tempor orci in auctor ultrices. Aliquam condimentum elementum euismod.</p>
```